# Combining categories within channel tag category parameter

Tags: channel-entries, categories

This is my code:

```
{embed="jobs-opportunities/.main_job_list" cats="14&85|14&240"}
```

You'll see I'm trying to list entries that are either from 1 set of categories or another. I feel the above should work but it doesn't. It doesn't work when I put it into the channel entries tag either, rather than an embed.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks,
Julie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both operators on channel:entries module. Try [Dandy Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dandy-cat), that allows you to use "(14&85)|(14&240)".

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. The inclusive `&` operator in the `category` parameter will return entries with all the categories, but it looks like you can't use that along with stacking `|`